# Laravel 5.1 - How to set the loginPath in AuthController?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I want to change the default Laravel routes from **/auth/login** to just **/login** and vis-à-vis with register.

These are my routes:

```
Route::get('login',     ['as' => 'getLogin', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin']);
Route::post('login',    ['as' => 'postLogin', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin']);
Route::get('logout',    ['as' => 'getLogout', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout']);
Route::get('register',  ['as' => 'getRegister', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister']);
Route::post('register', ['as' => 'postRegister', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister']);
```

Now the problem arises, that when a user tries to access an area that is guarded, the **Authentication** class kicks in, redirecting the unauthenticated user back to **/auth/login** instead of just **/login**.

I though I could solve the problem by setting the **$loginPath** in my **AuthController** like this:

```
protected $loginPath = '/login';
```

But it seems like the **$loginPath** is just used for unsuccessful login attempts, instead of unsuccessful authentication attempts, like documented in the **AuthenticateUsers Class**.

Well I managed to change the redirectURL in the **Authenticate Class** from this:

```
return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
```

to this:

```
return redirect()->guest('login');
```

Which solved the issue, yet I would like to set a property for this in my **AuthController** like this:

```
protected $redirectIfMiddlewareBlocks = '/login';
```

For this I check in the Authenticate Class if a property exists, which I set in the AuthController before:

```
return redirect()->guest(property_exists($this, 'redirectIfMiddlewareBlocks') ? $this->redirectIfMiddlewareBlocks : '/shouldnotbeused');
```

Yet I get the **/shouldnotbeused** url, instead of the one set by the **redirectIfMiddlewareBlocks** property in my AuthController.

How do I set up the path for the login route in my AuthController correctly?

Comment: Why are you checking if it exists? You know it exists because you just added it

Comment: As far as I can remember, those are the only 2 places you need to set the login path. But I don't see why you're overcomplicating things with setting the property and checking if it exists. I would just go with what works `redirect()->guest('login')`

Comment: Well, I was just a little bit refactoring and thought it would be a good idea, to  have this path saved in a variable somewhere at the top. And I check if it exist to see if it finds it, which it doesn't

Comment: But why the check? Will the property ever not exist?

Comment: To see if it actually accepts a poperty which is set in the authcontroller. Which it doesn't. Also I understand the implications of your question. You are saying why bothering checking if a property exists, if you set it first. Well I was reading some traits and got the idea, that it doesn't hurt to give the user of a class the option set a property, which differs from the default and then maybe not set it at all. But the option should be there. Hope you understood...

Comment: Yes, sorry if this wasn't clear: I guess the problem is not really serious enough. I had thought initially, that it would be neat to be able to define all paths in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are checking the property on the wrong class. You are checking if it exists on `$this`, which is an instance of **Authenticate** when it is set on **AuthController**

So you should change your check to:

```php
property_exists(AuthController::class, 'redirectIfMiddlewareBlocks')
```

Also, you can't access a protected property from another class. If you want to do that you'll have to make it public. Finally, I would make it static so that you don't have to instantiate an AuthController object to access it. So the final solution is:

```php
class AuthController {
    public static $redirectIfMiddlewareBlocks = '/here';
}
```

And in your Authenticate middleware:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;

class Authenticate {
    public function handle() {
        return redirect()->guest(
            property_exists(AuthController::class, 'redirectIfMiddlewareBlocks')
                ? AuthController::$redirectIfMiddlewareBlocks
                : '/shouldnotbeused'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much andrew.

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness you're welcome. Sorry I misunderstood at first. What I **thought** you were doing was nonsensical but what you were actually doing, I think is a good idea, as you said, to keep all the redirect paths in one place

Comment: Also there is still one problem. With your solution I get: Use of undefined constant AuthController - assumed 'AuthController'

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness ah, yeah check my update. `property_exists` needs the class name, so I changed it to AuthController::class